# How to find duplicate elements in a string array and store the result in another array

Tags: ruby

I have a string array:

```
Array1 = ["ab", "cd", "ab", "cd", "ef"]
```

I am trying to find all duplicate elements in `Array1` and store them in another array `Array2`. In this case `"ab"` and `"cd"` should be stored in `Array2`.

I tried this:

```
Array2 = Array1.detect{ |c| Array1.count(c) > 1 }
```

But it returns only the first duplicate element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way.

```
arr = ["ab", "cd", "ab", "cd", "ef"]

arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
   .select { |_,v| v > 1 }
   .keys
  #=> ["ab", "cd"]
```

We first use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to compute:

```
g = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
  #=> {"ab"=>2, "cd"=>2, "ef"=>1}
```

then [Hash#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) (not [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)) to obtain:

```
h = g.select { |_,v| v > 1 }
  #=> {"ab"=>2, "cd"=>2}
```

and lastly, [Hash#keys](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-keys) to extract the keys from `h`:

```
h.keys
  #=> ["ab", "cd"]
```

Another way is to use a set:

```
require 'set'

s = Set.new
arr.select { |e| !s.add?(e) }.uniq
  #=> ["ab", "cd"]
```

[Set#add?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) attempts to add the value of `e` to the set. If it is able to do so, it returns `self` (which evaluates `true`); if it's unable to do so (because the value of `e` is already in the set, implying that there are at least two elements of `arr` with the value of `e`), it returns `nil`. In the later case we want to select that  element of `arr`, so we write `!s.add?(e)`, which evaluates `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
array2 = array1.select { |item| array1.count(item) > 1 }.uniq
```

Comment: Glad it helped :-) Anytime!

Comment: @sawa : Could you please explain, which is the most efficient way?

Comment: If `n = array.size`, `count` examines each element of `array n` times, so `n**2` operations are required. It's more efficient to determine frequencies by using a counting hash (as I did), or [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) or sets.

Comment: Totally! I'll admit this was a rather naïve approach - though I do like that it's very readable and easy to reason about. You solution is very clever thuogh, @CarySwoveland.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#each_with_object` method :

```
array2 = array1.uniq
               .each_with_object([]) { |e, a| a << e if array1.count(e) }
```